# Camel Jetty Component write to Outputstream

Tags: http, apache-camel, jetty, httpconnection

I have a long running process in Camel, which is triggered by an HTTP-Request. I would like to write Status-Updates to the Outputstream, but i don't get the Response on the Client-Side.

I tried using the following:

Camel-Route:

```
<from uri="jetty:http://localhost:12345/myservice"/>
<process ref="test" />
```

The Processor Test:

```
public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("TestProcessor");
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) arg0.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_SERVLET_RESPONSE);

    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream());
    BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(wr);
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
        w.write("Zeile: " + x + "\n");
        w.newLine();
    }
//      arg0.getIn().setBody("This might also be a response");
}
```

And the Calling Code:

```
final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
            conn.setDoOutput( true );
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
            conn.setRequestMethod( "GET" );
            conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
            conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
            conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
            conn.setUseCaches( false );
            new Thread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if(!urlParameters.isEmpty()){
                            try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
                               wr.write( postData );
                               wr.close();
                            }
                        }
                        InputStream s = conn.getInputStream();
                        System.out.println("got InputStream");
                        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(s);
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
                        String line;
                        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                            System.out.println("ReadLine: " + line);
                        }

                        conn.disconnect();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }).start();
```

But i only get a response when i set the body in the processor (the commented line). Is there any way to keep the connection in camel and continue writing to it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `out` message to send an answer with the HTTP Component :

```
arg0.getOut().setBody("This might also be a response");
```

The HTTP Component use a `HttpBinding` to convert a `HttpServletRequest` to an `Exchange`, and the opposite, fill a `HttpServletResponse` from an `Exchange`. You can see the default implementation [here](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-http-common/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/http/common/DefaultHttpBinding.java#L250) or provide your own.